# What is the best way to write a select count query based on three and conditions?

Tags: mysql, sql, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I tried jpa query to get result based on spring data jpa.

My db have lots of records. There are many fields but I am interested you can say in field1, field2 and timestamp field. Field1 and field2 non unique fields and timestamp field is based on Java Localdatetime. Whenever new record coming I need to count totalnumber of records that matches from last 5 minutes records from db and matched with field1 and field2.

I tried following way to query to get result

```
   @Query(select count(table1) from table1 where table1.field1=?1 and 
     table1.field2=?2 and table1.timestampfield>=?3)
     public Long getTotalNumberofRecords(Field1 field1, Field2 field2, 
     TimestampField timestampfield).
```

I am getting null instead of totalnumberofoccurences from previous records.
Any other better alternatives that improves this code performance as well as solve my problem. Any nested query I need to use or self join something?

Comment: Without your source data or an example SQL fiddle it's a little hard to tell, but I'd guess that your criteria simply isn't returning results. If you execute the select statement without looking for a count (e.g. select *), do you return records?

Comment: Performance and the query not returning the correct result are not the same thing.

Comment: I have not tried to get only records. and it's realtimedata I can not test on SQL fiddle.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen first of all I want to get the result  anyway then I will see performance part.

Comment: Get it working, then worry about performance. It sounds like you don't actually know if you're supposed to get a result or not. With nothing better to go on, I'd be checking that your timestampfield is correct. That's some seriously bad variable naming going on there....

Comment: And of course you can test on SQL fiddle. You don't need to be testing on real data, just test data to confirm the logic. Once you know the logic is correct, then worry about getting it working in real time.

Comment: The posted code is not compilable Java, please post actual code that demonstrates the behaviour you are describing.